# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Unresponsive

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-4

I can't get the Carousel to work in Bootstrap 4.0.0 and I'm tearing my hair out... Everything's connected and semantically correct, but the JavaScript just won't fire, no matter the browser.

jQuery and Bootstrap.js are being loaded in the footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://sunset.dev/wp-content/themes/embark/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.0.0'></script>
```

Bootstrap.css is being loaded in the header:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://sunset.dev/wp-content/themes/embark/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

This is the HTML I am using (which is inside the `<header>` of an `<article>` inside the `.container` div):

```
<div id="post-gallery-46" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item  active background-image" style="background-image:url(http://sunset.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/room.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item  background-image" style="background-image:url(http://sunset.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/moose.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item  background-image" style="background-image:url(http://sunset.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/brain.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item  background-image" style="background-image:url(http://sunset.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/andrew.jpg);"></div>
    </div><!-- carousel-inner -->
</div><!-- .carousel slide -->
```

`.active` never toggles off the first item. The gallery just sits there like a dead trout.

I have also tried the same HTML markup with `<img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">` (with those same urls) inside of each `<div class= "carousel-item">` to no avail.

I even tried explicitly calling the carousel function on the div.

I'm already balding, so help a man out?

Comment: It'll help us help you if you'd publish a CodePen or something of your problem

Comment: You should also have Popper.JS. See the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

Comment: also BS4 uses class=img-fluid for it to be responsive